# Sign of Lagrangian and stress-energy tensor for relativistic dust

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, conventions, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I enjoy the derivation of $T_{\mu\nu} = \rho u_\mu u_\nu$ by Dirac, reproduced in [this Phys.SE question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17604/). But when I try to rewrite it with metric convention $(-+++)$ (used by MTW), I find a rather puzzling result.

The action for the relativistic dust should now be:
$$
S_M = -\int \rho c \sqrt{-v_\mu v^\mu} \sqrt{ |\det g| } d^4 x
        = -\int c \sqrt{-p_\mu p^\mu} d^4 x
$$
since $v_\mu v^\mu < 0,\, p_\mu p^\mu < 0$, while the rest of the derivation remains almost the same, which is:
$$
    \delta S_M
        = - \delta \int c \sqrt{-{p}_\mu {p}^\mu} d^4 x =
$$
$$
        = - \int c {\delta(-g^{\mu\nu} {p}_\mu {p}_\nu)
            \over 2\sqrt{-{p}_\alpha {p}^\alpha}} d^4 x =
$$
$$
        = \int c { {p}_\mu {p}_\nu
            \over 2\sqrt{-{p}_\alpha {p}^\alpha}}
            \delta(g^{\mu\nu}) d^4 x =
$$
$$
        = \int c { \rho v_\mu \rho v_\nu
            \sqrt{ |\det g| }^2
            \over 2 \rho c \sqrt{ |\det g| } }
             \delta(g^{\mu\nu}) d^4 x =
$$
$$
        = \int {1\over2} \rho v_\mu v_\nu
             \delta(g^{\mu\nu}) \sqrt{ |\det g| } d^4 x
$$
From which we calculate the stress energy tensor using the standard GR formula for it:
$$
    T_{\mu\nu}
        = - {2\over\sqrt{ |\det g| }}{\delta S_M\over\delta g^{\mu\nu}} =
$$
$$
        = - {2\over\sqrt{ |\det g| }} \left(
                {1\over2} \rho v_\mu v_\nu \sqrt{ |\det g| }
            \right)=
$$
$$
        = - \rho v_\mu v_\nu
$$
As you can see, it gives an extra minus sign. Clearly I've done something stupid, but I just couldn't spot it. Please help me find that mistake (or mistakes) in the above derivation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does metric signature affect the stress energy tensor?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/228185/)

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of convention. You'll find that [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/228185/does-metric-signature-affect-the-stress-energy-tensor) and the first answer are relevant. Essentially your formula is consistent with the requirement that  $T^{00}$ is positive, which is one possible way of fixing the sign of the stress-energy tensor. For this convention to be maintained when flipping the metric signature, one must introduce a minus sign in the definition of the stress-energy tensor, which the person in the question you're quoting didn't do. This doesn't mean their derivation is wrong: they are just following a different convention.